# Using Excel's Bloomberg API to find a stock's IPO date?

Tags: bloomberg

I am wondering if there is a function in Excel's Bloomberg API to find a stock's IPO date.

For example, given 'YELP US Equity', it should return 03/01/2012.

Given '700 HK Equity', it should return 06/16/2004.

Is there a way?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the field **EQY_INIT_PO_DT**

```
=BDP("YELP US Equity", "EQY_INIT_PO_DT")
```

and more in general, you can use the FLDS command over a security to search for all available data.

Comment: thank you for your comment. So is it like "=BDH("YELP US Equity", "EQY_INIT_PO_DT") = 03/01/2012?

Comment: @JunJang: no, it's like =BDP("YELP US Equity", "EQY_INIT_PO_DT")